# How to properly setup custom handler404 in django?

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) this should be fairly simple: I just need to define `handler404`. Currently I am doing, in my top `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

handler404 = 'myapp.views.handle_page_not_found'
```

The application is installed. The corresponding view is just (for the time being I just want to redirect to the homepage in case of 404):

```
def handle_page_not_found(request):
    return redirect('homepage')
```

But this has no effect: the standard (debug) `404` page is shown.

The documentation is a bit ambiguous:

- where should `handler404` be defined? The documentation says in the `URLconf` but, where exactly? I have several applications, each with a different `urls.py`. Can I put it in any of them? In the top `URLconf`? Why? Where is this documented?
- what will be catched by this handler? Will it catch `django.http.Http404`,  `django.http.HttpResponseNotFound`, `django.http.HttpResponse` (with `status=404`)?

Comment: What's `DEBUG` in your settings? If it's `True`, can you change it to `False` and see?

Comment: @ShangWang: thanks! Indeed, setting it to `False` solves the problem. This is not documented, afaik.

Comment: @delavnog - Its in the [error reporting sections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/error-reporting/#error-reporting) - "When DEBUG is False,..."

Comment: @Sayse: in a completely different context (Email reports, ...), and not related to error handlers. It would make more sense to mention this in the corresponding paragraph, but I digress ...

Comment: @delavnog - I was just more pointing out that it does mention that it mentions it there, it hints at it under the section in settings for [debug](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#debug) about how it handles error pages, and there are lots of other references to `DEBUG` throughout :)

Comment: @Sayse today's moment of unintended comedy: 6 years later and that link leads to, appropriately, a 404 error :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As we discussed, your setup is correct, but in settings.py you should make `DEBUG=False`. It's more of a production feature and won't work in development environment(unless you have `DEBUG=False` in dev machine of course).

Comment: I change mine to `False` in development mode, and still default django error pages show.

Comment: You have to use DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', False) == 'True'

Answer (score 12):

All the other answers were not up to date. Here's what worked for me in Django 3.1:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500, handler403, handler400
from your_app_name import views

handler404 = views.error_404
handler500 = views.error_500
```

views.py

```
def error_404(request, exception):
   context = {}
   return render(request,'admin/404.html', context)

def error_500(request):
   context = {}
   return render(request,'admin/500.html', context)
```

Note, you will have to edit this code to reflect your app name in the import statement in urls.py and the path to your html templates in views.py.

Comment: If you have a TemplateView? ```index_view = never_cache(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

Why you could not do `return index` inside `error_404`  function?

Comment: @realnot - Perhaps you could. Did you try? There are often more than one way to solve a problem.

Comment: I solved. `def error_404(request, exception): return index_view(request)`. `index_view` is a template that return a template response, you have to pass a request. +1 for your suggestion. Is the correct one!

Comment: in `urls.py` change `handler404 = views.error_404` to `urls.handler404 = views.error_404` and import urls as follow `from django.conf import urls`

Comment: @HajrasElGdiryHG Simply to be more explicit?

Answer (score 11):

**Debug** should be **False** and add to view `*args` and `**kwargs`. Add to urls.py `handler404 = 'view_404'`

```
def view_404(request, *args, **kwargs):
return redirect('https://your-site/404')
```

If I didn't add args and kwargs server get 500.

Answer (score 6):

To render **404 Error responses** on a custom page, do the following:

In your project directory open `settings.py` and modify `DEBUG` as follows:

```
    DEBUG = False
```

In the same directory create a file and name it `views.py`, insert the following code:

```
   from django.shortcuts import render

   def handler404(request, exception):
       return render(request, 'shop/shop.html')
```

Finally open `urls.py` file which is in the same project directory and add the following code:

```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from . import views

   handler404 = views.handler404

   urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   ]
```