# save Django2.2 404 request in database using middelware

Tags: django, middleware, django-2.2

i write a custom middilware to save all request in my database.
this is my code:

```
class TestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
      def process_response(self, request, response):
           ....
           # save my request attr in database
           HttpRequestLog.objects.create(**params)
           ...

     def process_exception(self, request, exception):
           ....
           # save my request attr in database
           HttpRequestLog.objects.create(**params)
           ...
```

i have a problem.
when user call a wrong url apis , Django return 404 status but this code save nothing to my database and i have n't any error!!!

```
               HttpRequestLog.objects.create(**params)
```

my code is worked when api returned 200 or 204 or 201 status.

Comment: A 404 is often done by an *exception*, not a HTTP response, you will thus need to "catch" the error, log the response, and reraise it.

Comment: i write it into process_exception but not working!

Comment: @Sifb71 From your settings show the `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat  MIDDLEWARE = [...
myapp.middleware.request_log_middleware.TestMiddleware ...
]

Comment: my middelware worked but i can not save anything to database when 404 accur..in 200 or 500 worked!

Comment: @Sifb71: can you [define a custom 404 handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35156134/67579)?

Comment: def response404(request,exception):
    return JsonResponse({"error": "This URL Not Find!"}, status=404)


handler404 = response404

Comment: i tested without custom 404 handler but not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem!

I use a revision middleware in my code and I change my middleware sort and place my middleware above revision middleware and every thing is successfully worked!

Answer (score 0):

A 404 is often done by an *exception*, *not* a HTTP response. It is then the Django framework that converts this exception into a HTTP 404 response.

You thus can "catch" the error, log the response, and reraise it:

```
class TestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        …
        # save my request attr in database
        HttpRequestLog.objects.create(**params)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, Http404):
            # …
        return None
```